# Can't make the gameobject move from another Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D STG game like Touhou series as I'm quite new to Unity.I get in trouble in controlling the enemies' bullet, especially where those bullets to move that I want.
Here are my two scripts that I think they have some problems.
First is EnemyAttackBehavior. I try to design the enemy can shoot bullet straightly and snipe the player. I find I can spawn bullet in this Script, but I can't change the bullet position.

```
public class EnemyAttackBehaviors : MonoBehaviour{
public float bulletSpeed;
public float attackCD;
public float eachWaveCD;
public int oneWaveAmount;

public enum AttackFunctionName
{
    StraightAttack, SnipeAttack,
}

public AttackFunctionName attackFunction;

private int checkNumber;
private float nextShotTime;

private void Start()
{
    checkNumber = (int)attackFunction;
    nextShotTime = Time.time;
}
private void Update()
{
    CheckWhatTypeAttack();
}

private void CheckWhatTypeAttack()
{

    if (checkNumber == 0)
        StraightAttack();            
    else if (checkNumber == 1)
        SnipeAttack();
}

private void StraightAttack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < oneWaveAmount; i++)
    {
        if (Time.time > nextShotTime)
        {
            GameObject t = ObjectPool.TakeFromPool("EnemyBullet");
            t.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
            //t.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, -bulletSpeed);
            //t.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * -bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            t.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, bulletSpeed, 0);
            nextShotTime = Time.time + attackCD;
        }
    }
}

private void SnipeAttack()
{

}
```

}
In the code StraightAttack. I try three ways to change the bullets' position. The only one can change bullets' position is rigibody2D.velocity. But I don't like this way because using this way I can't measure the speed value I want easily. Unfortunately, the others ways can't change the bullets' position.I don't know why the bullets' position don't change when I modify the value directly (like t.transform.position -= new Vector3 (0, bulletSpeed, 0)).Then I think maybe the error is in another script - Stage1Path.

```
public class Stage1Path : MonoBehaviour{
public float firstWave = 4f;

private float timer;
private bool w1Check = true;
private void Start()
{
    timer = 0f;
}

private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    CheckWhatWave();
}

private void CheckWhatWave()
{
    if (Time.time > firstWave && w1Check == true)
        FirstWave();
}

private void FirstWave()
{
    GameObject e1 = ObjectPool.TakeFromPool("Enemy");
    e1.transform.position = new Vector3(-2f, 3f, 0f);
    EnemyBehaviors e1Script = e1.GetComponent<EnemyBehaviors>();
    e1Script.moveSpeed = 0.01f;
    e1Script.moveFunction = EnemyBehaviors.MoveFunctionName.VerticalMove;
    e1Script.lifeTime = 3f;
    
    EnemyAttackBehaviors e1AttackScript = e1.GetComponent<EnemyAttackBehaviors>();
    e1AttackScript.attackCD = 0.1f;
    e1AttackScript.attackFunction = EnemyAttackBehaviors.AttackFunctionName.StraightAttack;
    e1AttackScript.bulletSpeed = 4f;
    e1AttackScript.eachWaveCD = 3f;
    e1AttackScript.oneWaveAmount = 5;

    w1Check = false;
}
```

}
In Stage1Path, I try to spawn the first enemy named e1 in FirstWave(). It happen after the game starts 4 seconds. In FirstWave(), I set e1's movement by the script EnemyBehavior. It works pretty well! But when I use the same way in e1's shooting type. the bullets' were spawn but they didn't move. I don't know the error happens in EnemyAttackBehavior or Stage1Path. I try to fix this bug for many hours and searching a lot of Internet.I also try to use coroutine in EnemyAttackBehavior, I think it may solve the problem. But I still failed. Any help is very appreciated. And sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply translation every frame. This line is good, but

```
t.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * -bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In your case you apply it only once because of this. So you basically move it once in one frame and then wait for other time to move it once again.

```
    if (Time.time > nextShotTime)
    {
      // movement logic
      nextShotTime = Time.time + attackCD;
    }
```

It works with modifying velocity, because the movement based on velocity is calculated by physics engine. In case of transform.Translate, you need to apply movement every frame by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. But I wonder CheckWhatTypeAttack() is in Update(), and StraightAttack() is in CheckWhatTypeAttack(), why I only apply it once? It should update perframe in my logic because it is in Update? You are right and thank you, but now I don't understand the relationship between CheckWhatTypeAttack() and Update().

Comment: Yes, basically it is in `Update()`. `Update()` -> `CheckWhatTypeAttack()` -> `StraightAttack()` and here is a problem with checking `nextShotTime` This checking prevents from every frame movement.